# Open website with C and search through source code

Tags: c, web

I made a program in C that is supposed to try a bunch of numbers on a url, like this:

example.com/cbc001 ...com/cbc002

The program runs throught from 000 to 999 and is supposed to add those numbers after the 3 letters in the url. I managed to get the program to run through all numbers, 000-999.

Now my problem is I have no idea how to open a website in C, and I don't really want to open it in a browser, what I just need is the program to try all those urls ".com/abc990" and then I want to check the source file of the webpage to search for a certain word.

How could I approach this?

Comment: You might find [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) helpful

Comment: Possible [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648857/can-fopen-be-used-to-open-the-url).