# Is it safe to not call curl_multi_cleanup()?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, libcurl

I was reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26648931/6872717 and decided to fix that code and improve it to be able to use it as a library.

It is one of the examples in the libcurl web page:  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fopen.html

I found out that although the libcurl documentation states this referring to the function [`curl_multi_init()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_init.html):

> This init call MUST have a corresponding call to curl_multi_cleanup
>   when the operation is complete.

the example code doesn't call it, ever.

In a program, it can be easy to add that call at the end of the main, but for a library, it is more difficult (or maybe impossible) to know if the multi handle can be cleaned up.  Is it valid to omit the call?

I guess that constitutes a memory leak, but not a very big one, and it's only once, and I don't know how to avoid it.

---

Would it be OK to write a `__attribute__((destructor))` `url_deinit()` function so that if the user forgets to call it, it would be called anyway, or would the resources already be destroyed at that moment and produce UB?

Comment: That depends; If you really can "prove", that the amount of the memory leak is static and minor, it could be tolerated. On the other hand, consider that your library itself provides a cleanup function, which in turn calls the curl cleanup routines.

Comment: The function that calls it is probably marked with `__attribute__((destructor))`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne No, in the linked example, the function `curl_multi_cleanup()` is indeed not called at all

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never clean it up, you will never get the memory and resources "back" that is allocated in relation to that handle.

In the fopen.c example, the multi handle is global and is reused and is indeed never freed. That's fine if you're fine with never getting the memory back.

When your program exits, all memory and resources will be freed forcibly anyway.